# Как вывести слово из объекта в Javascript?

Tags: javascript, объекты

У меня есть кусок кода для работы с радио. Для решения задачи мне необходимо понять, как вывести слово из объекта по ключу не меняя каркас программы.
Привожу листинг:

```
var nato = (function() {
  var letters =  {
    "A": "Alpha",  "B": "Bravo",   "C": "Charlie",
    "D": "Delta",  "E": "Echo",    "F": "Foxtrot",
    "G": "Golf",   "H": "Hotel",   "I": "India",
    "J": "Juliett","K": "Kilo",    "L": "Lima",
    "M": "Mike",   "N": "November","O": "Oscar",
    "P": "Papa",   "Q": "Quebec",  "R": "Romeo",
    "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango",   "U": "Uniform",
    "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray",
    "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"
  }

  return function(word) {

  }
})()
```

Мне необходимо вывести значение буквы A.

Comment: т.е. вам надо оставить все функции как есть, и вы не знаете что надо добавить после return function(word) { ...?

Comment: Да, суть задачи вообще принять строку и по ней вывести слова в словаре. Мне для понимания необходимо для начала сначала одну вывести. Вот пример nato('abc') // --> 'Alpha Bravo Charlie'. Вот решение на Python http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_tmMjnjF6gg_2.py.

Comment: понятно, у вас получится функция-замекание, которая содержит ссылку на letters. при вызове этой функции происходит возврат значения, которое находится в свойствующем свойстве letters.
посмотрите [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475936/196972).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После `return function(word) {` добавьте `return letters[word];`, так:

```
return function(word) {
   return letters[word];
}
```

а чтобы получить слово, после `... })();` пишете так:

```
var word = nato("A");   // вернет Alpha  
alert(word);
```

пример - [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/opqdLzv2/).

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо сделать трансляцию, например, `"ABC"` в `"Alpha  Bravo Charlie"`, то так:

```
var nato = (function() {
    var letters =  {
        "A": "Alpha",  "B": "Bravo",   "C": "Charlie",
        "D": "Delta",  "E": "Echo",    "F": "Foxtrot",
        "G": "Golf",   "H": "Hotel",   "I": "India",
        "J": "Juliett","K": "Kilo",    "L": "Lima",
        "M": "Mike",   "N": "November","O": "Oscar",
        "P": "Papa",   "Q": "Quebec",  "R": "Romeo",
        "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango",   "U": "Uniform",
        "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray",
        "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"
    }       
    return function(word) {
        var res = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {              
            res.push(letters[word[i]]);
        }
        return res.join(" ");
    }
})();
var w = nato("ABC");
alert(w);
```

Answer (score 3):

Может так?

```
console.log(letters["A"]);
```

Comment: Как вариант,но нужно отретюрнить.

Comment: - Вы, что же, и пальцы за меня загибать будете? - Ага!

Comment: С этим я справлюсь =)